# Cannot include external classes in build files in sbt+intellij

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to use some classes from org.apache.commons in my Build.scala file but it is always complaining that the classes I want cannot be found. When they are included on the top of the source files, it is okay. So the same library, if included in source files, okay; if included in build files, error. What do I need to do to get include to work in Build.scala?

To clarify, for libraries used by the source, you can add to the

libraryDependencies ++= ...

line of the build.sbt file

But what to do with libraries needed by the build files itself? It appears that

those items added to libraryDependencies ++= ...

cannot be used by the build files (.scala one).

Answer (score 1):

You're adding libraries for the meta-build. You should put the setting in project/build.sbt, rather than build.sbt. Take a look at the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive) for a better understanding.

A simple demo:

```
$ mkdir project

$ cat > project/build.sbt
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.3.0.RC3"

$ cat > build.sbt
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods

{
  println(JsonMethods)
  libraryDependencies ++= Nil
}

$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/thirstycrow/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/thirstycrow/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/thirstycrow/tmp/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/thirstycrow/tmp/project/}tmp-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$@7addc5e4
[info] Set current project to tmp (in build file:/Users/thirstycrow/tmp/)
```

Comment: Have you ever used this?

Comment: @marios No, not actually. I tend to write plugins to do something complex. But it definitely works this way. I added a simple demo. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is really nice! Now I understand the recursive nature of the build much better.